# How to solve FlutterJNI.loadLibrary called more than once?

Tags: backgroundworker, background-process, uilocalnotification, background-service, flutter-local-notification

when I run the project, I am facing the error:

W/FlutterJNI( 8009): FlutterJNI.loadLibrary called more than once

I/ResourceExtractor( 8009): Found extracted resources res_timestamp-1-1700998719201

W/FlutterJNI( 8009): FlutterJNI.prefetchDefaultFontManager called more than once

W/FlutterJNI( 8009): FlutterJNI.init called more than once

i tagged the callbackDispatcher function with @pragma('vm:entry-point') but it didn't solve the problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SI2S.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yb9Vq.jpg)